# Creating a new column that can equal one of many columns depending on condition (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns

I have a wide pandas dataframe with a number of variables with titles of the form 'crimeYR.' For example, crime1996 is a dummy variable that tells me if an observation has been convicted of a crime up until the year 1996, crime1998 tells me whether he/she has been convicted of a crime up until 1998, and so forth. Everyone in the dataset is born in different years and I would like to create a single variable that tells me whether or not a person has committed a crime by age 25. Here is an example of what I would like to create

```
birthYR  crime2006 crime2008 crime2010 crimeby25
1981         0         1         1         0
1981         1         1         1         1
1983         0         1         1         1
1982         0         0         1         0
```

I have a general idea of how one might code it in stata, but I am struggling to get it to work in python. Here's an idea of how it might work in stata:

```
gen crimeby25 = 0
foreach v of num 2006/2016{
     replace crimeby25 = crime`v' if `v' - birthyr == 25
}
```

What's a simple way of doing what I'm trying to do in Python?

Comment: Why row 1 is 0 ? Since it crime in 1998 and 1998-1981 < 25 , so should this consider as crime ?

Comment: Sorry, I made an error in the columns. The column titles have been fixed so that the variable crimeby25 now produces the right result.

Comment: Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)? What's your original df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. You have the following dataframe :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'birthYR': [1981,1981,1983,1982],
                   'crime2006': [0,1,0,0],
                   'crime2008': [1,1,1,0],
                   'crime2010':[1,1,1,1]})

df

birthYR  crime2006 crime2008 crime2010 crimeby25
1981         0         1         1         0
1981         1         1         1         1
1983         0         1         1         1
1982         0         0         1         0
```

Let's first define the list of years that we are studying :

```
years = [2006,2008,2010]
```

We create a few intermediary useful columns

```
for year in years :
    # Compute the age at a given year
    df["AgeIn"+str(year)] = year - df["birthYR"]

    # Is he/she more than 25 at a given year
    df["NotMoreThan25In"+str(year)] = df["AgeIn"+str(year)]<=25

    # Let's remove age column for clarity
    df = df.drop("AgeIn"+str(year),axis=1)

    # Check if he/she commited crime and was not more than 25 at a given year
    df["NotMoreThan25In"+str(year)+"AndCrime"] = df["NotMoreThan25In"+str(year)]*df["crime"+str(year)]
```

In the end, we just sum the total on each year to see if he/she commited crime by 25 :

```
df["crimeby25"] = df[["Not25In"+str(year)+"AndCrime" for year in years]].max(axis=1)

df["crimeby25"]

0    0
1    1
2    1
3    0
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. The only change I needed to make was to take the max rather than the sum in the last bit of code you provided. Some people had been convicted of crimes multiple times by the age of 25 so the sum command yielded occasional values of 2 and 3. Taking the max ensured that all the values of df['crimeby25'] were either 0 or 1.